# how fix the y-axis's rate in plot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, polyfills

I am using a line to estimate the slope of my graphs. the data points are in the same size. But look at these two pictures.  the first one seems to have a larger slope but its not true. the second one has larger slope. but since the y-axis has different rate, the first one looks to have a larger slope. is there any way to fix the rate of y-axis, then I can see with my eye which one has bigger slop?

code:

```
x = np.array(list(range(0,df.shape[0]))) # = array([0, 1, 2, ..., 3598, 3599, 3600])
    df1[skill]=pd.to_numeric(df1[skill])
    fit = np.polyfit(x, df1[skill], 1)
    fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)
    df['fit_fn(x)']=fit_fn(x)
    df[['Hodrick-Prescott filter',skill,'fit_fn(x)']].plot(title=skill + date)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that your question doesn't include any of the code you used to actually generate the plots you show; you probably don't need any code at all for this question

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

One, use [`matplotlib.pyplot.axis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html) to get the axis limits of the first figure and set the second figure to have the same axis limits (using the same function) (could also use [`get_ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim) and [`set_ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim), which are specific to the y-axis but require directly referencing the Axes object)

Two, plot both in a [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) figure and set the argument `sharey` to True (my preferred, depending on the desired use)

Comment: I have 1000 images

Comment: So use the first method, getting and setting the axis limits

Comment: Also, there's almost certainly a better way to present your information than by making 1000 plots. That many plots is just noise after a while, and doesn't really help anyone. If they're just for you, that's another thing.